# How to remove rows with NULL / Zero (0) in R

Tags: r

```
     CampActID  AccountID           LocationName    LocationID
       <int>     <chr>                    <chr>      <int>
1         12         3            Mark + Brandy          3
2         12        15                     NULL          0
3         12       102                 Spuntino        100
4         12       126                     NULL          0
5         12       128 Intersport Concept Store        312
6         12        15                     NULL          0
7         12        48              Aspeli Dame         46
8         12        75            Albert Bistro         73
9         12       126                     NULL          0
10        12       128 Intersport Concept Store        312
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: If it is a character "NULL", then do `library(dplyr);df1%>% filter(LocationName != "NULL" & LocationID!=0)`

Comment: Now I replaced 0 with NA.                                                                                                                                                                CampActID AccountID             LocationName LocationID
       <int>     <chr>                    <chr>      <int>
1         12         3            Mark + Brandy          3
2         12        15                     NULL         NA
3         12       102                 Spuntino        100
4         12       126                     NULL         NA

Comment: > CampAct <- CampAct[!apply(is.na(CampAct) | CampAct == "NULL" , 1, all),]
> CampAct

Comment: Now I used like that. It's working fine.

Comment: CampAct%>% filter(LocationName != "NULL")

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun    http://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun

Comment: @KumarP I posted my comment as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>%
   filter(LocationName != "NULL" & LocationID!=0)
```